# Make some characters as invisible from an existing PDF document by using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I tried to read the "Tj" operator from an existing PDF by using Apache **PDFBox.**
When i achieved completely this task, i tried then to replace some characters. For example let us consider a pdf document containing (hello world)Tj, so this code replaces "hello" to "hi123".
Therefore the modified document becomes containing (hi123 world)Tj instead of (hello world)Tj.

My big problem now is how to edit this code in order to make "hello" as text rendering mode 3 (in other terms: text rendering mode "invisible"). So i don't want to replace "hello" by "hi123", but to make "hello" as disappear (mode invisible). And therefore, the modified document becomes containing just "world" where "hello" became invisible.

My code so far:

```
public class Test1 {
    private static Test1 tes; 
    private static final String src="...";
    private static PDPageContentStream content;
    private static PDType1Font font; 

    public static void CreatePdf(String src) throws IOException, COSVisitorException{
        PDRectangle rec= new PDRectangle(400,400);
        PDDocument document= null;
        document = new PDDocument();
        PDPage page = new PDPage(rec);
        document.addPage(page);
        PDDocumentInformation info=document.getDocumentInformation();
        info.setAuthor("PdfBox");
        info.setCreator("Pdf");
        info.setSubject("Stéganographie");
        info.setTitle("Stéganographie dans les documents PDF");
        info.setKeywords("Stéganographie, pdf");
        content= new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
        font= PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
        String texte="hello world";
        content.beginText();
        content.setFont(font, 12);
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(15, 385);   
        // content.appendRawCommands("3 Tr");
        content.drawString(texte);
        content.endText();
        content.close();
        document.save("doc.pdf");
        document.close();       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        tes= new Test1();
        tes.CreatePdf(src);
        PDDocument doc ;
        doc = PDDocument.load("doc.pdf");
        List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();  
        for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++)  {
            PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);  
            PDStream contents = page.getContents();  
            PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream()); 
            parser.parse();  
            List tokens = parser.getTokens();  
            for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++)  
            {  
                Object next = tokens.get(j); 
                if (next instanceof PDFOperator)  {
                    PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;  
                    // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF  
                    if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj"))  
                    { 
                        // Tj takes one operator and that is the string  
                        // to display so lets update that operator 
                        COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);  
                        String string = previous.getString();  
                        System.out.println(string);
                        //Word you want to change. Currently this code changes word "hello" to "hi123"
                        string = string.replaceFirst("hello", "hi123"); 
                        previous.reset();  
                        previous.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));
                    }
                }      
            }
            // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);  
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();  
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);  
            tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);  
            page.setContents(updatedStream);
        }
        doc.save("a.pdf"); 
        doc.close();  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially you have to change the `tokens` list by replacing the two tokens `(hello world) Tj` by the eight tokens `3 Tr (hello) Tj 0 Tr ( world) Tj`

Thus, replace your loop

```
List tokens = parser.getTokens();  
for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++)  
{
    [...]
}
```

by something like

```
List tokens = parser.getTokens();  
for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++)  
{  
    Object next = tokens.get(j); 
    if (next instanceof PDFOperator)
    {
        PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;  
        // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF  
        if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj"))  
        { 
            tokens.set(j-1, COSInteger.get(3));
            tokens.set(j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
            tokens.add(++j, new COSString("hello"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
            tokens.add(++j, COSInteger.get(0));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
            tokens.add(++j, new COSString(" world"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
        }
    }      
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to thank you!!!! :)
I tested your code and my problem is completely resolved.

Thank you again!!!

Liszt.

Answer (score 1):

**Final code :**

```
    public class Test1 {
    private static Test1 tes; 
    private static final String src="...";
    private static PDPageContentStream content;
    private static PDType1Font font; 
    public static void CreatePdf(String src) throws IOException, COSVisitorException{
    PDRectangle rec= new PDRectangle(400,400);
    PDDocument document= null;
    document = new PDDocument();
    PDPage page = new PDPage(rec);
    document.addPage(page);
    PDDocumentInformation info=document.getDocumentInformation();
    info.setAuthor("PdfBox");
    info.setCreator("Pdf");
    info.setSubject("Stéganographie");
    info.setTitle("Stéganographie dans les documents PDF");
    info.setKeywords("Stéganographie, pdf");
    content= new PDPageContentStream(document, page);
    font= PDType1Font.HELVETICA;
    String texte="hello world";
    content.beginText();
    content.setFont(font, 12);
    content.moveTextPositionByAmount(15, 385);   
    // content.appendRawCommands("3 Tr");
    content.drawString(texte);
    content.endText();
    content.close();
    document.save("doc.pdf");
    document.close();       
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, COSVisitorException {
        // TODO code application logic here   
           tes= new Test1();
           tes.CreatePdf(src);
           PDDocument doc ;
           doc = PDDocument.load("doc.pdf");
           List pages = doc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();  
           for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++)  {
              PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);  
              PDStream contents = page.getContents();  
              PDFStreamParser parser = new PDFStreamParser(contents.getStream()); 
              parser.parse();  
              List tokens = parser.getTokens();  
                for (int j = 0; j < tokens.size(); j++)  
            {  
                  Object next = tokens.get(j); 
                     if (next instanceof PDFOperator)  {
                       PDFOperator op = (PDFOperator) next;  
                    // Tj and TJ are the two operators that display strings in a PDF  
                             if (op.getOperation().equals("Tj"))  
                    { 
                        // Tj takes one operator and that is the string  
                        // to display so lets update that operator 
                               //COSString previous = (COSString) tokens.get(j - 1);  
                               //String string = previous.getString();  
                               //System.out.println(string);
                               //Word you want to change. Currently this code changes word "hello" to "hi123"
                              // string = string.replaceFirst("hello", "hi123"); 
                              // previous.reset();  
                              // previous.append(string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"));                    
            tokens.set(j-1, COSInteger.get(3));
            tokens.set(j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
            tokens.add(++j, new COSString("hello"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));
            tokens.add(++j, COSInteger.get(0));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tr"));
            tokens.add(++j, new COSString(" world"));
            tokens.add(++j, PDFOperator.getOperator("Tj"));






                    }
                 }      
            }
                // now that the tokens are updated we will replace the page content stream.
            PDStream updatedStream = new PDStream(doc);  
            OutputStream out = updatedStream.createOutputStream();  
            ContentStreamWriter tokenWriter = new ContentStreamWriter(out);  
            tokenWriter.writeTokens(tokens);  
            page.setContents(updatedStream);
    }
      doc.save("a.pdf"); 
      doc.close();  
    }
}
```